# Android Widget use app:srcCompat for ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget

I have Widget with ImageView. When i use **android:src** for set image for **ImageView** everything all right, but when i use **app:srcCompat** image don't show.
Is there a way to use app:srcCompat in Android Widget?

It's set in my project:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android {  
 defaultConfig {  
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }
}


  minSdkVersion 24
  targetSdkVersion 29
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. ImageView doesn't actually have a `app:srcCompat` attribute (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView)).
The reason why you're normally able to use it, is that ImageView is automatically replaced by AppCompatImageView when you use the appcompat library. However this doesn't work with widgets since they are based on RemoteViews. As you have seen, with RemoteViews you can only use ImageView and not AppCompatImageView. Even if you add the appcompat library to your own app, the problem is that the RemoteViews object for your widget will be handed to the process of the app that will display the widget (typically the launcher), where we can't assume appcompat to be available.

Are you trying to use appcompat because of problems with your vector assets? If you describe the problem you're having with them maybe we can find a way to make it work with regular ImageViews.

Comment: I am using vector assets with gradients. My min is api 23. So is it ok if i use android:src ?

Answer (score -1):

Try `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>` instead if `<ImageView>`

Comment: AppCompatImageView not supported by the Widget  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout